# Sql parameter warning

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that I would like to query from my HTML form. I tried so many formats and conditions but this one is the only one that comes close to what I'm trying to achieve. I'm new to this and I need help. I do not know what I'm missing to show out-put.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $Summary=$_POST['summary'];
    $Status=$_POST['status'];
    $Priority=$_POST['priority'];

    $db=mysql_connect (" ") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' .  mysql_error()); 

    $mydb=mysql_select_db(" ");
}

$where = '';
if(isset($Status) && !empty($Status)){
    $where .= "status ='$Status' AND ";
}
if(isset($Priority) && !empty($Priority)){
    $where .= "priority ='$Priority' AND ";
}
if(isset($Summary) && !empty($Summary)){
    $where .= "summary ='$Summary' AND ";
}

$sql= "select * from data $where";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 

if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0){ 
    echo "No Match Found"; 
}else{ 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $Not_Completed=$row['Not Completed'];
        echo $Completed=$row['Completed'];
        echo $Miscommunications =$row['Miscommunications'];
        echo $Not_Given_Access=$row['Not Given Access'];
        echo $Unskilled=$row['Unskilled'];
        echo $Missing_Parts=$row['Missing Parts'];
        echo $High=$row['High'];
        echo $Medium=$row['Medium'];
        echo $Low=$row['Low'];
        echo $EFirst_name =$row['EFirst_name'];
        echo $ELast_name=$row['ELast_name'];
        echo $Employee_id=$row['Employee_id'];
    }
}
```

And here is my HTML form:

```
<select name="status"> 
    <option>status</option>
    <option>Completed</option>
    <option>Not Completed</option>
</select>

<select name="priority"> 
    <option>priority</option>
    <option>High</option>
    <option>Medium</option>
    <option>Low</option>
</select> 

<select name="summary"> 
    <option>summary</option>
    <option>Miscommunications</option>
    <option>Not Given Access</option>
    <option>Unskilled</option>
    <option>Missing Parts</option>
</select>

<div align="right"><input type="submit" value="Search">
```

I get a Warning of: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 191 // "if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)"...

All suggestions are welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: `$sql= "select * from data $where";` Error, you'll always have `AND` at the end, echo out the query and see what you get

Comment: Your script seems to be vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: If this is a new project, you should switch to `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL`.  Click [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for more information.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Same result

Comment: @rtcherry sorry but this is an ongoing project. I'm using phpmyadmin with MySQL 5.5. Is there another way for me to query this database through my form to get the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$conditions = array();

if(isset($Status) && !empty($Status)){
  $conditions[] = "status ='$Status'";
}
if(isset($Priority) && !empty($Priority)){
  $conditions[] = "priority ='$Priority'";
}
if(isset($Summary) && !empty($Summary)){
  $conditions[] = "summary ='$Summary'";
}

$where = '';
if (!empty($conditions)) {
  $where = "WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}

$sql= "SELECT * FROM data $where";
```

**Edit**: Can you please post the result of this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $Summary=$_POST['summary'];
    $Status=$_POST['status'];
    $Priority=$_POST['priority'];

    $db=mysql_connect (" ") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error()); 

    $mydb=mysql_select_db(" ");
} else {
    echo "I might not be connected to a database...";
}

echo 'Connection error? ' . mysql_error();

echo 'Ping Result: ' . mysql_ping() === FALSE ? 'Not connected.' : 'Connected.';

$conditions = array();

if(isset($Status) && !empty($Status)){
  $conditions[] = "status ='$Status'";
}
if(isset($Priority) && !empty($Priority)){
  $conditions[] = "priority ='$Priority'";
}
if(isset($Summary) && !empty($Summary)){
  $conditions[] = "summary ='$Summary'";
}

$where = '';
if (!empty($conditions)) {
  $where = "WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}

$sql= "SELECT * FROM data $where";

echo "SQL Command: $sql";

$result = mysql_query($sql); 

echo 'Query error? ' . mysql_error();

if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0){ 
    echo "No Match Found"; 
}else{ 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $Not_Completed=$row['Not Completed'];
        echo $Completed=$row['Completed'];
        echo $Miscommunications =$row['Miscommunications'];
        echo $Not_Given_Access=$row['Not Given Access'];
        echo $Unskilled=$row['Unskilled'];
        echo $Missing_Parts=$row['Missing Parts'];
        echo $High=$row['High'];
        echo $Medium=$row['Medium'];
        echo $Low=$row['Low'];
        echo $EFirst_name =$row['EFirst_name'];
        echo $ELast_name=$row['ELast_name'];
        echo $Employee_id=$row['Employee_id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't particularly useful information.  Are you certain you have successfully connected to the database?  Please see my edit.

Comment: Search Projects Details

SQL Command: SELECT * FROM data 
Search Employee or Customer either by letter, first or last name   
A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z

( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 201
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0019 168328 {main}( ) ..\search.php:0
2 0.0077 175288 mysql_num_rows ( ) ..\search.php:201
No Match Found

Comment: @drscmd1 I think I edited after you ran that code.  I am expecting to see "Connection error?" and "Query error?" in the output.  Also, I expect to see something from "Ping Result: ".

Comment: I think that there is something wrong in the way i set up my HTML page. My form action=search.php?go and I'm able to show results for the Search either by letter, first or last name but when I add this script from above to the search.php file I'm not getting nowhere. Is there a email I can contact you and send you this file to look at for me please?

Comment: results: I might not be connected to a database...Connection error? Connected.SQL Command: SELECT * FROM data Query error? No database selected

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select * from data where $where";
```

Also, here:

```
if(isset($Status) && !empty($Status)){
$where .= "status ='$Status' AND ";
}
if(isset($Priority) && !empty($Priority)){
 $where .= "priority ='$Priority' AND ";
}
if(isset($Summary) && !empty($Summary)){
    $where .= "summary ='$Summary' AND ";
}
```

if, more than 1 `if` are `true` then there will be a trailing `AND`

Add this after the `if`s:

```
$where .= '1=1';
```

Comment: This will not work if no `$Status`, `$Priority`, or `$Summary` is set.  Also, no matter what there will be a trailing `AND`.

Comment: @draxxxeus still the same outcome

Comment: @draxxxeus I changed it to what rtcherry posted above and still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

When mysql_num_rows() reports this error, (in 99%) of the cases your query is wrong.

```
$sql= "select * from data $where";
```

There seems the `where` keyword to be missing. Add it if `$where` isn't empty.

Like:

```
$sql= "select * from data ".(empty($where)?"":"where ".substr($where, 0, -5)); // substr, for trimming the "AND"
```

Comment: I still get a Warning of: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 191 // "if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)"...

Comment: @rtcherry see my substr there?

Comment: @bwoebi Ah, no I misread that.  My bad.  Deleted the comment.

Comment: @bwoebi it returns this: SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 200 // if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0){ 
echo "No Match Found"; 
}else{

Comment: @bwoebi How do I do this?? print mysql_error(); I new to this but I do try hard...

Comment: @drscmd1 You should add this line before your if (mysql_num_rows...)

Comment: @rtcherry if/when you get a chance pls email at swinson_darren@yahoo.com Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query is malformed and is causing the error. When you specified the `$where` in your query string, you forgot to include the `WHERE` statement. You need to do: `$sql= "select * from data where ".$where;`

Answer (score 0):

try changing this part of code

```
if(isset($Status) && !empty($Status)){
$where .= "status ='$Status' AND ";
}
if(isset($Priority) && !empty($Priority)){
 $where .= "priority ='$Priority' AND ";
}
if(isset($Summary) && !empty($Summary)){
    $where .= "summary ='$Summary' AND ";
}
```

to this code

```
$check = 0;
if(isset($Status) && !empty($Status)){
$where .= "status ='$Status'";
$check++;
}
if(isset($Priority) && !empty($Priority)){
 if($check != 0){
  $where .= " AND ";
 }
 $where .= "priority ='$Priority'";
 $check++;
}
if(isset($Summary) && !empty($Summary)){
 if($check != 0){
  $where .= " AND ";
 }
    $where .= "summary ='$Summary'";
}
```

Comment: This will cause problems if you set `$Priority` and not `$Status`.

Comment: While that works, the implementation could be much cleaner by doing something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638198/sql-parameter-warning/16638364#16638364).

Comment: change this code 
$sql= "select * from data where $where"; , you forgot to add WHERE clause :-)

Comment: @DepH WHERE clause??? do you mean from my original sql???

$sql="(SELECT status, priority, employee_Employee_id, EFirst_name, ELast_name From project, employee WHERE status in ('Not Completed', 'Completed') 
AND priority in('High', 'Medium', 'Low') AND employee_Employee_id = Employee_id)"

Comment: no not there, i am talking about this code $sql= "select * from data $where"; , change this code to $sql= "select * from data WHERE $where";